# Specific IIS Setting programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

Setting explained on this picture:

[image: Image explaining settings]

How can i change this IIS setting using C#?

I tried setting application pool credentials (on this web application) but it doesn't apply this setting.
How can I do this programmatically using C#?

Comment: did you figure this out?